# Issues with .mobile.loadPage and external page in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

In my jquery mobile application I have one page that I want to load external content.

Trying to follow the docs, and my code doesn't produce any script errors, but my external content does not load.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;

        //Initialize page container per docs 
        $("#staff-directory-container").pagecontainer({ defaults: true });

        //Get external content into DOM
        $.mobile.loadPage("http://another.domain.com/myContent.html", {
        pageContainer: $('#staff-directory-container')
            });

    });
```

Thanks in advance for any help offered....
Chris

Comment: <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="staff-directory">

    <div data-role="content" id="staff-directory-container">

        <h3 class="content-heading center">Staff Directory</h3>


    </div>

</div>

Comment: When ajax is disabled, you __cant__ use `.loadPage` because it uses Ajax to fetch HTML contents.

Comment: Omar, I have set ajaxEnabled = true, but am still not loading the external page, do you see anything else that appears missing or wrong?

Comment: use `$("#staff-directory-container").pagecontainer("load", "file.html");` and dont use `.ready()` in jQM. When do you want to load that page? on which stage?

Comment: I would like to load that page after a button click event.

Answer (score 0):

To bind events in jQuery Mobile, use `pagecreate` which is equivalent to `.ready()`. To load an external page, use [`.pagecontainer("load", "target", { options })`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-load) as `.loadPage()` is deprecated and will be removed in jQM 1.5.

In your case, `$.mobile.pageContainer` is `$("#staff-directory-container")`. And note that Ajax should be **enabled**.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {
  $("#loadBtn").on("click", function () {
    /* define new pagecontainer then load */
    $.mobile.pageContainer = $("#staff-directory-container").pagecontainer();
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("load", "myContent.html");
  });
});
```

Comment: Omar, thanks, now getting: Error: cannot call methods on pagecontainer prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'load'

Comment: My code below results in no errors, but does not load the content into my pagecontainer:

Comment: yea, I just tested it @ChristopherCrisis I've updated my answer.

Comment: $(document).on("pagecreate", "#mobile-index", function () { //mobile-index is the page with the button, not the pagecontainer
            $("#staff-directory-container").pagecontainer({ defaults: true });
            $("#get-staff-directory").on("click", function () {
                $("#staff-directory-container").pagecontainer("load", "http://foo.com");
            });
        });

Comment: @ChristopherCrisis I've tested the code and it works. Are you still getting any errors?

Comment: Hi Omar, yes, I am... my content is not loading, and I wonder if it is because it is on a different domain... From the JQM docs: " When Ajax isn't possible (such as a non-same-domain url, or if specified using certain attributes on the link), a normal HTTP request is used instead."

Comment: Here is my button code: <a href="#staff-directory" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" id="get-staff-directory" data-ajax="false">Staff Directory</a>

Comment: @ChristopherCrisis `data-ajax=false` = Ajax disabled. Check if other domain allows content sharing (CORS), if yes, you can use Ajax.

Comment: Omar, still not working for me. How can I get the remote content to load when the page is loaded, rather than on a click event? Something like:

Comment: $(document).on("pagecreate", "#staff-directory", function () {
       
                /* define new pagecontainer then load */
                $.mobile.pageContainer = $("#staff-directory-container").pagecontainer();
                $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("load", "http://myurl.com");

        });

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49902/discussion-between-omar-and-christopher-crisis)