# jQuery mobile : 'pageinit' not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm using jQueryMobile 1.4.4 on Worklight.

**EDIT :** I have a main html `index.html` which contains a div `#pageContent`. What I'd like to do is to include the external pages in this block, in order to maintain the header / footer and skeleton of the `index` page that should be generic to all the app.

I was facing an issue which is that when loading an external HTML page into a div in the main page, the Jquery style is not applied, because the styles / JS has not been interpreted yet. Using this :

```
function wlCommonInit () {
    $("#pageContent").load ("pages/login-view.html");
)};
```

then following the jquery mobile doc, to make sure that everything on the main page is being loaded before rendering an external HTML page I have changed it to :

```
function wlCommonInit () {

    $(document).on ("pageinit", function () {

        alert ("Hello there");

        $.mobile.loadPage (
            "pages/login-view.html"
            ,{ 
                "pageContainer": $("#pageContent")
            }
        )}
    );
}
```

but this code is not being fired and the alert doesn't appear.

Is something wrong with my code ?

Comment: what kind of style not applied ??????

Comment: @rajeshkakawat jQM UI (styles), read more about jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Please clarify your question. You want to load another _External page_ once _current page_ is created? Or you want to load _external content_ into current page once created?

Comment: @Omar, Thank you :) Please see my Edit. I'd like to load external content into the current page. and style the new loaded content with all the styles included in `index.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load *content* into current page, use `.load()`. However, loaded *content* requires *enhancement* to load jQM UI (styles) `.enhanceWithin()`. This method applies jQM styles to all elements in spite of their type (widget).

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {
    $(".selector").on("click", function () {
        $("#targetDIV")
            .load("page.html #specificDIV", function () {
            $(this).enhanceWithin(); /* apply styles */
        });
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/42bcm5cx/)**

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery Mobile, you'll need to replace the entire `<div data-role="page" ...>`. I don't think you can replace only part of the content (that is, keep the header and footer, and replace only the what's in between).

For example, in the below code snippets mainpage.html's contents is loaded/replaces that of index.html on application launch:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>index</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
            <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
            <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
            <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body style="display: none;">
            <div data-role="page" id="mainpage" style="padding-top: 42px !important">
                <div data-role="content">
                </div>
            </div>

            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change','pages/mainpage.html');
}
```

**mainpage.html**

```
<div data-role="page" id="mainpage" style="padding-top: 42px !important">
    <div data-role="header" id="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>jQuery Mobile Page Navigation</h3>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" id="content" style="padding: 15px">
        In mainpage.html
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. what do you mean by `:mobile-pagecontainer` ? So if I understand, I'll need to load the footer and header everytime, right ?

Comment: that's the way to load pages in jQuery Mobile 1.4 and above. Or one way, I suppose.

Comment: So I'll need to include the header and footer div in every page, right ?

Comment: Unfortunately. (Unless @Omar will have a better suggestion).

Comment: That makes me confusing, so what could be the purpose of `loadPage` http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.loadPage/  ?

Comment: It is the 'old' way to load external content. Use page container. It is mentioned in the note section.

Comment: I have found this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457764/issues-with-mobile-loadpage-and-external-page-in-jquery-mobile will try it, if doesn't work, I'll go with your answer and accept it :)

Comment: I'm not saying that replacing pagecontainer with loadpage in my code above won't work. It might as well work, but you should not use deprecated API methods.

Comment: @Andro-Begg [`:mobile-pagecontainer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24173950/1771795). If you want to load _contents_ you dont need to use `.loadPage` or `.pagecontainer("load")`. This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22458908/1771795) is to define a new _pageContainer_.

Comment: @Omar : then to load content, what Should I do ? Thank you.